# Extension method for nested generic type

Tags: c#, generics

I'm writing an extension method, that should work on a generic of generics, say `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` - for example

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SelectAll<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source)
{
    return source.SelectMany(x => x);
}
```

Now, how do I make it accept a parameter that's actually a `List<List<T>`? I've only been able to make it swallow a `List<IEnumerable<T>>`, is there a way without manually casting to that?

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working nicely, what's the problem you're having?

```
var w = new List<List<int>>(){
    new List<int>{2,3,4},
    new List<int>{5,3,2}
};

w.SelectAll().Dump();
```

Comment: Oh, looks like my problem is only with code complete in Visual Studio, then... I can live with that, thanks for pointing it out.